# What is the best way to transfer a file using Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing code for uploading a file from a client to my server and the performance isn't as fast as I think it should be.

**I have the current code snippet that is doing the file transfer and I was wondering how I could speed up the transfer.**

Sorry about all of the code:

```
InputStream fileItemInputStream ;
OutputStream saveFileStream;
int[] buffer;
while (fileItemInputStream.available() > 0) {
    buffer = Util.getBytesFromStream(fileItemInputStream);
    Util.writeIntArrToStream(saveFileStream, buffer);
}
saveFileStream.close();
fileItemInputStream.close();
```

The Util methods are as follows:

```
public static int[] getBytesFromStream(InputStream in, int size) throws IOException {
    int[] b = new int[size];
    int count = 0;
    while (count < size) {
        b[count++] = in.read();
    }
    return b;
}
```

and:

```
public static void writeIntArrToStream(OutputStream out, int[] arrToWrite) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrToWrite.length; i++) {
        out.write(arrToWrite[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reading a single byte at a time will be horribly inefficient. You're also relying on `available`, which is rarely a good idea. (It will return 0 if there are no bytes *currently* available, but there may be more to come.)

This is the right sort of code to copy a stream:

```
public void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32*1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

(The caller should close both streams.)

Comment: don't I have to worry about my unsigned bytes in the file overflowing in Java's signed bytes?

Comment: They are mp3 files, if it matters

Comment: No, you don't. This is just reading and writing, not performing any sort of arithmetic or transformation.

Comment: And/or look into using the BufferedInput/OutputStream classes.